# UITextChecker without proper nouns

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, spell-checking

I'm exercising the UITextChecker class to do a quick check on a string for a word-spelling game. Works a little TOO well. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, the only methods that operate on this class return "correct" words that also include proper nouns. I would like to check my strings against a list of common words that do NOT include proper nouns. Here's my code so far:

```
    //Test the answer for a word
    UITextChecker *checker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
    NSString *testString = wordString;
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,0);
    range = [checker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:[testString lowercaseString] 
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [testString length]) 
                                        startingAt:0 
                                              wrap:NO 
                                          language:@"en_US"];
    if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
        spelledWord = YES;

    } else {
        spelledWord = NO;

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have u stored list of common words anywhere like in array.?

Comment: hp iOS Coder: I've tried storing all common words in an array (and also tried putting them in a set), and then checking the testString against all of them. This method works, but it is much too slow for my purposes, and puts an incredible amount of strain on the framerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the easiest way but you could put a second condition. First store an array with proper nouns (or other words you don't want) elsewhere in your code do a search on Google if you can't think of them. (I've adapted this slightly from a method i use)

```
if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
int i = 1;
NSString *p;
foundrand = FALSE;
if ([[MyArray sharedKelArray].Myarray count] >2){
        ////NSLog(@"GOTTEN - %d", choosennumber);
        while(i<[[MyArray sharedKelArray].Myarray count])//would check that if equal
        {
            p = [[[MyArray sharedKelArray].Myarray objectAtIndex:i] NSString];
            NSLog(@"Checking word - %d",p);



               if (testString == p){
                    NSLog(@"Matched");
                    spelledWord = NO;
i = 5 + [[MyArray sharedKelArray].Myarray count];

                }
                i+=1;

        }
        spelledWord = YES;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: That is a good suggestion. I'll give it a try. However, my experience with checking my testString against words in an NSArray or an NSSet seriously slows down the frame rate and the response is slow. The UITextChecker is nearly instantaneous and does not the affect frame rate of the objects animating on the screen.

Comment: Unless you're trying to use this with 1000s of words it should cause no noticeable drop in the frame rate. I use this in one of my games and fps stays steady.

Comment: Well, I think I will be using it with over 1000 words... so I guess I'll keep up my search. This approach works fine for a start. Thanks!